# Prove $1(1!)+\dots+n(n!) = (n+1)!-1$ using induction

Tags: discrete-mathematics, summation, induction, factorial

So I'm trying to prove this statement (through induction):

$$1(1!)+2(2!)+\dots +n(n!)=(n+1)!-1$$

But I'm confused with the inductive step here:

$$(n+1)!-1+[(n+1)(n+1)!] = (n+2)!-1$$

What do I do at this point? The factorial is throwing me off, because I can't multiply $(n+1)(n+1)!$ together to simplify the left side, can I?

Answer (score 6):

Hint:

$$(n+1)!+(n+1)(n+1)!=(n+1+1)[(n+1)!]=(n+2)(n+1)!=(n+2)!$$

Comment: Well that makes things a LOT simpler, my question is - is there a way to come to this algebraically? Or is it just something you learn/remember over time?

Comment: @TaiM. I did arrive at the result algebraically. All I did was factor.

Comment: Ah, now I see what you did, I was a little confused because I didn't see how (n+1)! * n would get you (n+1) but I see it now.

Answer (score 0):

From the induction step we get: $$(n+1)!-1+[(n+1)(n+1)!]=(n+2)!-1$$
Now let's add and subtract (n+1)! from the right side of the equation, in order to get the form of the induction assumption on the right side too: $$(n+1)!-1+[(n+1)(n+1)!]=(n+2)!+(n+1)!-(n+1)!-1=(n+1)!-1+[(n+2)!-(n+1)!]$$
from the induction assumption we can simplify the equation: $$[(n+1)(n+1)!]=[(n+2)!-(n+1)!]$$
 $$[(n+1)(n+1)!]=[(n+2)(n+1)!-(n+1)!]$$
 $$[(n+1)(n+1)!]=[(n+2-1)(n+1)!]$$
 $$[(n+1)(n+1)!]=[(n+1)(n+1)!]$$

And that's what we were looking for.